# PHP Getting Values From Nested Array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to get the 'name' value from within a 'nested array' I am not sure if thats the correct term in PHP.

```
   Array ( 
        [0] => Array 
        ( 
            [event] => Array 
                ( 
                    [id] => 28140972 
                    [name] => Northwich v Lincoln United FC 
                    [countryCode] => GB 
                    [timezone] => Europe/London 
                    [openDate] => 2017-03-08T19:45:00.000Z 
                ) 
                [marketCount] => 24 
        ) 
        [1] => Array 
        ( 
            [event] => Array 
                ( 
                    [id] => 28140974 
                    [name] => Viimsi MRJK v Paide Linnameeskond II 
                    [countryCode] => EE 
                    [timezone] => Europe/London 
                    [openDate] => 2017-03-08T17:00:00.000Z 
                ) 
                [marketCount] => 24 
        ) 
    }
```

I am trying to access the 'name' key of every item in the array, but struggling to do it. Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$arrayOfNames = array_map(function ($item) {
    return $item['event']['name'];
}, $yourPreviousArray);
```

Test case:

```
>>> print_r($data)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [event] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => James
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [event] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [name] => Jim
                )

        )

)
=> true
>>> array_map(function($item) {
... return $item['event']['name'];
... }, $data)
=> [
     "James",
     "Jim",
   ]
>>>
```

Comment: Trying this, but its bringing back nothing for me :( thanks

Comment: I need to see all of your code then to see what's going wrong.

Comment: got it working by changing the return to echo ;) thanks!

Comment: `array_map()` isn't really meant to echo from inside the callback, it would probably be better to foreach over the result of it and output the results, but I guess if that works, it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
foreach ($array as $item) {
    echo $item['event']['name'].'<br/>';
}
```

Comment: Thats what I have been trying (at least I know I am on the right track) thanks - but its just bringing back nothing